# Import modules inside of an __init__ file

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to create a module with several folders inside of it, each with their own `__init__.py` file. My file structure looks like this:

```
| module
| __init__.py
| module1
|| __init__.py
|| a.py
| module2
|| __init__.py
|| b.py
```

I'm trying to make it so when I reference the original module, I can do something like this:

```
module.module1.a()
```

But when I try to import the modules within the top level `__init__.py`, it says that the modules aren't found. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have to use the top module name, as in `import module.module1` in the top level `__init__.py`.